# c# - How to enable button if I input a text on my textbox

Tags: c#

In my C# form I want to disable my button whenever I input some text on the textbox. Is there any best way to do this ?

Comment: What are you using? Windows Forms or XAML?

Comment: What have you tried and what's the problem your having? You need to provide more information

Answer (score 1):

Set the `button.Enabled` property in the `TextChanged` event:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using WPF, if so here is an answer that is very relavent: [Enable button based on TextBox value (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427782/enable-button-based-on-textbox-value-wpf)